# owl-carousel never shows items

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a problem with owl-carousel that only the prev and next button is shown but the items which i add into the owl-carousel never show (always display:none)
this is my HTML code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:10000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="my-slide">
      <ul class="row owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 1</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 2</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 3</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 4</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 5</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 6</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 7</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 8</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 9</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 10</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 11</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 12</p></a></div></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

Comment: I think replace class name owl-item to only item to li. Here is working example https://jsfiddle.net/qun0kv9n/1/

Answer (score 1):

I think .owl-carousel class needs to be placed in jquery initialization. Please check this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qun0kv9n/2/) and let me know.

```
 $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:10000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your .js is correct. You just need add **owl.carousel.min.css** into `<head>` and **owl.carousel.js** into `<body>` tag.

Add this

```
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

in `<head>` tag.

Then,

Add this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

on bottom of `<body>` tag (before `</body>`).

Answer (score 0):

I think You have forgot Add owl-carousel css and js file.

Please add owl-carousel css and js file

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/assets/owl.carousel.css">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:10000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
   });
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/assets/owl.carousel.css">



<section class="my-slide">
      <ul class="row owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"><p>this is item 1</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"><p>this is item 2</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg"><p>this is item 3</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg"><p>this is item 4</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg"><p>this is item 5</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg"><p>this is item 6</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 7</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg"><p>this is item 8</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 9</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 10</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 11</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 12</p></a></div></li>
      </ul>
    </section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.0/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't included `jquery` in the question and `owlcarousel css` file. including those files to your code will fix the issue. Please see below code.

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:10000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
   });
```

```html
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<section class="my-slide">
      <ul class="row owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 1</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 2</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 3</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 4</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 5</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 6</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 7</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 8</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 9</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 10</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 11</p></a></div></li>
        <li class="owl-item"><div class="item-cat"><a href="logIn.html"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i><p>this is item 12</p></a></div></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```